# Problem with Ito Isometry

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

I know that for one-dimensional case,
$$ E \left[ \left(\int^T_S f(t,\omega)dB_t \right)^2 \right] = E\left[ \int^T_S f^2(t,\omega) \, dt \right]$$
for adapted, measurable f that satisfies that are in $L^2(dt \times dP)$.

For $f = [f_{ij}(t,\omega)]$ and $n$-dimensional Brownian motion, we have 
$$ E\left[ \left|\int^T_S f(t,\omega)dB_t \right|^2 \right] = E \left[ \int^T_S |f(t,\omega)|^2 \, dt \right]?$$

where $|f|^2 = \sum f_{ij}^2$. I think to derive this, we need (for $j \neq k$)

$$E \left( \int^T_S f_{ij}\, dB_j \int^T_S f_{ik} \, dB_k \right) =0 ?$$

But I am not sure about the last assertion (by indep of the Brownian motions? but the $f$'s are not independent?). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For any $f \in L^2(\lambda \otimes \mathbb{P})$, we know that

$$\int_0^t f(s) \, dB_s$$

is $\mathcal{F}^B_t$-measurable. Here $\mathcal{F}_t^B := \sigma\{B_s; s \leq t\}$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the Brownian motion $B$.

If $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ are independent Brownian motions, this implies in particular that the random variables

$$\int_0^t f(s) \, dB_s$$

and

$$\int_0^t g(s) \, dW_s$$

are independent for any $t \geq 0$ and $f,g \in L^2(\lambda \otimes \mathbb{P})$ which are progressively measurable with respect to the corresponding (canonical) filtration.

Comment: thanks, but if I have $dX_t = X_tdB_1 + X_t dB_2$, then why $\int^t_0 X_sdB_1(s)$ and $\int^t_0 X_sdB_2(s)$ are still independent?

Comment: @poormaths Actually, you cannot expect that these expressions to be independent as $X_t$ obviously depends on $B_1$ **and** $B_2$.

Comment: so how can we come up with
$$ E[ |\int^T_S f(t,\omega)dB_t|^2] = E[ \int^T_S |f(t,\omega)|^2dt]$$

Comment: @poormaths So what are you actually asking for? That this equality holds is a fact, and it is proved in almost everybook on stochastic calculus. In order to get rid of the mixed terms of the form $$\int_S^T f(s) \, dB_s \cdot \int_S^T g(s) \, dW_s$$ one usually makes use of the fact that $$\int_0^T f(s) \, dB_s \cdot \int_0^T g(s) \, dB_s$$ is a martingale; hence has expectation $0$.